# Can't import google.cloud.vision

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, google-cloud-vision

I'm using Anaconda, and I'm trying to use google cloud vision, but I cannot import google cloud vision. I can import google cloud, but it throws an error below.

```
from google.cloud import vision
ImportError: cannot import name 'vision'
```

What module should I import with anaconda? 
(I've already imported `google-api-core`, `google-auth`, `google-cloud-bigquery`, `google-cloud-core`, `google-cloud-sdk`, `google-cloud-storage`, `google-resumable-media`, `google-resumable-media`, `googleapis-common-protos`)

Could anyone solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may need to add a dependency to [`google-cloud-vision`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/). To install the latest version, just run:

```bash
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

Comment: I couldn't find `google-cloud-vision` package in anaconda. Is there other ways to do so?

Comment: I successfully installed with `pip`. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 10):

You can install google-cloud-vision by typing:

```
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to convert with OCR from PDF to txt with Google Cloud**

```
import os
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types

#pip install google-cloud-vision

# Set up the Google Cloud Vision client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# Directory containing the PDF files
pdf_directory = "d:/doc/doc"

# Output directory for the TXT files
output_directory = "d:/doc/doc"

# Get a list of PDF files in the directory
pdf_files = [file for file in os.listdir(pdf_directory) if file.endswith(".pdf")]

# Process each PDF file
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_directory, pdf_file)

    # Create the output TXT file path
    txt_file = os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0] + ".txt"
    txt_path = os.path.join(output_directory, txt_file)

    # Read the PDF file as bytes
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        content = file.read()

    # Convert PDF to image using Google Cloud Vision API
    input_image = types.Image(content=content)
    response = client.document_text_detection(image=input_image)

    # Extract text from the response and save it as TXT
    text = response.full_text_annotation.text
    with open(txt_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(text)

    print(f"Converted {pdf_file} to {txt_file}")
```